# Is it true that there exists $\lambda >0$ for which $\lambda f(x)$ has a fixed point?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f:$ **R** $\rightarrow$ **R** be a continuous function which has at least 2 zeros. Is it true that there exists $\lambda >0$ for which $\lambda f(x)$ has a fixed point?

Comment: The family of lines $x/\lambda$ cover the first and third quadrants of the plane (excepting the axes). The only way for a continuous function to go from the second to the fourth quadrant would be to pass through the origin, but then that yields a fixed point.

Answer (score 2):

If $f(x) > 0$ for some $x > 0$ or $f(x) < 0$ for some $x < 0$ then putting $\lambda = x/f(x) > 0$ gives $x$ as a fixed point. Otherwise $f(x) \leq 0$ for all $x > 0$ and $f(x) \geq 0$ for all $x < 0$. Then you can show $0$ is a fixed point with any choice of $\lambda$. You don't need the assumption about having two zeros.